# ReactNative.Передача данных из TextInput в функцию

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

пишу приложение на react native,  мне нужно получить текст от пользователя(я это делаю с помощью TextInput), а затем передать этот текст в функцию для прогона через условия и записи в базу данных, опыта в работе с текстовыми полями мало, можете пожалуйста подсказать как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React позволяет вешать обработчики на разные события прямо из JSX [подробнее](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Для обработки изменения текста у `TextInput` существует событие `onChangeText`

```
const Component = () => {
  const handleChange(e) {
    console.log(e) // Здесь ваш обработчик
  }

  return (
      <TextInput
        onChangeText={handleChange} // (*)
      />
  );
};
```

В качестве аргумента для `onChangeText` передаем функцию, которая вызывается при изменении поля ввода